# How do I get 'npm test' to find my karma.conf.js file?

Tags: javascript, npm, jasmine, karma-runner

I have the following structure in my application:

```
Web (Asp net core)
|
|--wwwroot
|--ClientApp
|  |--app
|  |  |-- ... (typescript modules, *.spec.js files etc.)
|  |
|  |--karma.config.js
|  |--test-main.js
|
|--Controllers
|--config.json files for web etc.
```

In the console I'm in the ClientApp folder when running:

```
npm test
```

I get the following error:

```
File C:\Users\...\Web\karma.conf.js does not exist!
```

Why does it try to look for the `karma.conf.js` file in the Web folder?

How can I tell it to look in the right place? Even if I CD to the app folder I get the exact same error.

If I try to place the karma.conf.js file where it expects it, I get a bunch of other errors like:

```
cannot find module requirejs
```

I'm horribly confused, would really appreciate some help.

karma.conf.js file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

basePath: '',
frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
files: [
  'test-main.js',
  {pattern: 'test/**/*spec.js', included: false},
  {pattern: '*.js', included: false}
],
exclude: [
],
preprocessors: {
},
reporters: ['progress'],
port: 9876,
colors: true,
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
autoWatch: true,
browsers: ['Chrome', 'Firefox'],
singleRun: false,
concurrency: Infinity
})
}
```

test-main.js:

```
var allTestFiles = []
var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$/i

Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function (file) {
  if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
    var normalizedTestModule = file.replace(/^\/base\/|\.js$/g, '')
    allTestFiles.push(normalizedTestModule)
  }
})

require.config({
  baseUrl: '/base',
  deps: allTestFiles,
  callback: window.__karma__.start
})
```

Comment: Is your `package.json` also in the ClientApp directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go into your `package.json` and edit the `test` script to point to the location of your karma config.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ./path/to/karma.conf.js"
}
```

Comment: It was specified in my angular-cli.json file...A lot of examples that I used for inspiration did not have this file. Everything moves at such a fast pace that most examples are outdated within a couple of months. So confusing.